# Heckmann two-step in probit in R

Tags: r, probit, heckman

I haven't found an answer to this online: 
**Is there any package / easy to implement way to estimate a probit with heckman correction in R?** The corresponding function in STATA would be heckprob

Comment: you may wanna take a look at the sample selection package. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/vignettes/selection.pdf and here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/sampleSelection.pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment :-) I did look at the sample selection package, but still cant see an application for heckman probit :-(

Comment: I see. Here's a practical guide and implementation using the sample selection package: https://rpubs.com/wsundstrom/t_selection

Comment: thanks for the link :-) still, the regression of interest is OLS (the 2nd step), not probit :(.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). I suggest linking to a relevant, easily-obtainable data set (would the Smoke data in sampleSelection do?), and reporting the Stata output in your question. Then someone can help you get the same output in R.